# strtolower fails with arabic characters

Tags: php

my site is allow users to register with arabic/english names

i am trying to convert user first and last name to lower case

i am using this function

```
$first_name = strtolower ( $_POST['first_name'] );
```

if i try to put arabic name i get this encode ( ø¹ù„ø§ø¡ )

try it by your self

```
<?
echo 'مصر'; // return مصر
echo strtolower('مصر'); // return ø¹ù„ø§ø¡
?>
```

?>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use `strtolower` on UTF-8 encoded string, only on ISO 8859-1. Use **[`mb_strtolower()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)** instead. You also need to specify the encoding used, make sure it's set correctly (probably `"UTF-8"`).

```
<?
echo 'مصر'; // return مصر
echo mb_strtolower('مصر', 'UTF-8'); // return مصر
?>
```

Comment: There was nothing said about UTF-8. You should better say: `strtolower` does only work with ISO 8859-1.

Comment: @Gumbo: His output clearly tells it's a UTF-8 string. But yes, I suppose your description is more accurate.

Comment: @Truth did you tryed it? i got the same result!

Comment: i am trying to switch between browser encoding, i am getting results like this ���,ø¹ù„ø§ø¡, can you please try it again?

Comment: You're right... I'll try to see what the problem is and get back to you on that.